# DHARMa outlier test is significant, what are my next steps?

Tags: r, outliers, non-linear-regression, diagnostics

I'm looking for information and guidance to help me understand the outlier test in DHARMa for negative binomial regression. Here is the diagnostic plot from DHARMa using the function simulateResiduals().
[image]

First off, The dispersion test is significant in the plot. Using testDispersion() on the model and on the residuals, I get the results of 2.495. Visually, the dots seem to aline pretty well on the QQ line. The developer stated ' If you see a dispersion parameter of 1.01, I would not worry, even if the test is significant. A significant value of 5, however, is clearly a reason to move to a model that accounts for overdispersion.' [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490680/significant-dispersion-test) I conclude that the deviation is within the acceptable range for the NB regression.

Second, the Outlier test is also significant. I never had this before, and I can't find much information regarding how many outliers is okay vs not okay to have. Following the recommendation of DHARMa's developer, I looked at the magnitude of the outlier to investigate this. [reference](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html#general-remarks-on-interperting-residual-patterns-and-tests). Here is the code and output:

`ModelNB <- glm.nb(BUD ~ Treatment*YEAR, data=Data_Bud) simulationOutput <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = ModelNB, plot = T) testOutliers(simulationOutput, type = "binomial")`

`

```
    DHARMa outlier test based on exact binomial test with
    approximate expectations

data:  simulationOutput
outliers at both margin(s) = 12, observations = 576, p-value =
0.00269
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.007968127
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.01081011 0.03610864
sample estimates:
frequency of outliers (expected: 0.00796812749003984 ) 
                                            0.02083333
```

`
**Can someone help me understand this output? ** Is having 12 outliers per 576 observations okay? In statistics classes, I was told that taking out outliers was a big No-No. What does "true probability of success is not equal to 0.007968127" mean? I can't accept H1 and need to accept H0 for the outlier???

Information on my model:
`ModelNB <- glm.nb(BUD ~ Treatment*YEAR, data=Data_Bud)`

- BUD = The number of floral buds on a twig
- Treatment = 5 different fertiliser treatment
- YEAR = 2 different years (2020 and 2021)

Comment: If you need help interpreting results from statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I asked a very similar question today, how weird! Here's a link, maybe we'll get lucky and someone will answer. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/593771/outliers-and-possible-dispersion-in-neg-binomial-glmm-residuals-dharma-package

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick, I will post it there. I'm still learning the differences between all the StackOverflow interfaces (if we can call it that).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about model interpretation, not programming